# Saving a file multiple times

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to write a VBA script which edits a few cells, save the excel spreadsheet as a different name and as a csv file format. The issue I am having is repeating this process for multiple excel documents to be saved.

I have tried using a While loop however I have a feeling this stops working as soon as the first document is saved. The code works for the first excel spreadsheet but it doesn't make multiple files with different names.

```
Sub SaveFile()

Dim i As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim x As Integer

i = 1

x = InputBox("Enter the number of the Unit")
c = InputBox("How many Racks are in the Unit")

Do While i < c
If i < 10 Then
    Cells(2, 4).Value = x & "0" & i & "01"
    Cells(2, 6).Value = "RACK " & x & "0" & i & " /bal"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Test\" & x & "0" & i & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
    i = i + i
Else
    Cells(2, 4).Value = x & i & "01"
    Cells(2, 6).Value = "RACK " & x & i & " /bal"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Test\" & x & i & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
    i = i + i
End If
    i = c
Loop

End Sub
```

What I expect it to do is create multiple spreadsheet files with different values in each as well as a different name for each file all as a CSV format. What is actually happening is only one document is created by the values are perfect.

Comment: `Do While i < c` and after your first run you write `i = c`. You might want to look into that. A possible written solution would rather make use of a `For` loop. Also I would avoid using integers.

Comment: At the end of your loop you say `i = c` thus terminating the loop after one iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are looking for something like that:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SaveFile()
    Dim x As Long
    x = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter the number of the Unit", Type:=1)

    Dim c As Long
    c = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="How many Racks are in the Unit", Type:=1)

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 to c
        Cells(2, 4).Value = x & Format$(i, "00") & "01"
        Cells(2, 6).Value = "RACK " & x & Format$(i, "00") & " /bal"
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Test\" & x & Format$(i, "00") & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
    Next i
End Sub
```

Note that I used the [Application.InputBox method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox)  instead of the [InputBox function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/inputbox-function) because here you can specify a type `Type:=1` that forces the user to enter a number.

Also you don't need to check for `i < 10` instead just `Format$(i, "00")` to ensure the leading `0` on numbers `< 10`.

And you can use a `For i = 1 to c` loop which automatically increments `i` on `Next i` so you don't need to increment `i = i + 1`.

Comment: Very nice answer, helping to improve code in more than one way.